# Error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java

```
// readObject
fis = new FileInputStream(name: "C:\\code\\java\\asignment\\Student\\ListStudent2.dat");
ois= new ObjectInputStream( fis);
while(true) {
Student t = (Student) ois.readObject();
System.out.println(t.getName());
}
// write code
fos = new FileOutputStream(name: "C:\\code\\java\\asignment\\Student\\ListStudent2.dat", append: true); 
oos= new ObjectOutputStream(ous: fos);
oos.writeObject ( student);
oos.flush(); 
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

In write code , it work but i can't read object, I did implements Serializable.

I use while loop to read List Student but it just work in first loop and error  `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC`

I

I can't fix this problem. Can you hepl me

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: The problem is that you seem to be creating multiple `ObjectOutputStream` objects that append to the same file. This doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder this is (at least) the third question about similar problems in the last days. Nguyễn, you should take the [tour]: "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for" - searching for that error message on this site, shows [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+StreamCorruptedException%3A+invalid+type+code%3A+AC)